# Convert coordinate axes to angles

Tags: opengl, math

I'm now implementing opengl camera class and faced with the problem: how to properly convert coordinate axes to angles?

I've searched on the internet a lot, but found no working solutions and unfortunately math is black magic for me, so I cannot do it myself.

I have method in the camera class:

```
void Camera::LookAtTarget(const glm::vec3& targetPosition, const glm::vec3& upDirection)
{
    m_directionForward = glm::normalize(targetPosition - m_position);
    m_directionRight = -glm::normalize(
        glm::cross(upDirection, m_directionForward)); 
    m_directionUp = glm::normalize(
        glm::cross(m_directionForward, m_directionRight));

    // HOW TO GET ANGLES FROM THESE AXES?
}
```

Please help with some working code.

Comment: Why not just use [`glm::lookAt()`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00245.html#ga2d6b6c381f047ea4d9ca4145fed9edd5)? I'm pretty sure that you don't want to mess with angles.

Comment: I am holding rotation in angles and axes at same time. It is much more intuitive for user to operate with angles rather then quaternions or raw matrices.

Comment: You're probably looking for [matrix - euler angle conversion](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToEuler/).